# C++ functions problem

Tags: c++, function

Is there a way for functions to call each other i.e.

```
void menu()
{
some code here
play();
...
}

int play()
{
...
menu();
...
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it not work for you?

Comment: Yes I did and it didn't work. I'm a newbie I know :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the declaration of the second function at the top of your code file:

```
int play();

void menu()
{
   // some code here
   play();
   // ...
}

int play()
{
   // ...
   menu();
   // ...
   return 0;
}
```

This is called a [*forward declaration*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration), and it informs the compiler that an identifier will be declared later.
It is a way of denoting a function so that you can call it before you provide the complete definition.

Comment: Technically this is a good answer but in practice it will cause stack overflow.

Comment: Right. You have to make sure there is some logic inside the functions that prevents them from calling each other infinitely. That produces an infinite loop, and a stack overflow error. This can be as simple as a guard cause, implemented using an `if` statement. More information about recursive function calls is available [here, in a question that was just asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770597/recursive-loop-c).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but this is almost never what you want to do since careless use will break the stack.